# Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration in cpanel apache host

Tags: django, cpanel

the server return bellow Error when i run the Django in my  cpanel host  ?
what should i do ,Please?

```
Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```